# Can someone point the pcv valve in this car?

Tags: audi

I have audi a3 with 1.6L petrol engine that I believe it has a problem with the pcv valve and I don’t know where it’s located and the spare parts store don’t have my engine Diagram. Can someone point the pcv valve for me? I have attached two pictures that identical to my engine for you to see. Thanks in advance [image]

Comment: What year is the car? Might be able to rustle up a diagram etc for you.

Comment: @motosubatu thanks for the reply. My car is Audi a3 2001

Comment: Audi a3 2001 1.6L

Comment: Its not Diesel GdD. I have the symptoms of a pcv it’s look like the pcv valve is closed

Comment: Oops, where did I get the idea it was @FadiSalm? Still, what's the problem you're having?

Comment: 1.I have oil butter on the oil cap 2. I have a bit smoke when opening the oil cap but the oil level still the same no burning oil issue 3. I have oil in the pipe between the throttle and the air filter. These are the most clear symptoms

Comment: Which hose goes from your Intake manifold to the head of your Engine block ?

Comment: That's it right over there,  what ? you can not see me pointing ?

Answer (score 0):

It should be this one. Seemingly it´s integrated in the part below the oil filler cap.

[image]

Comment: Thanks I will go to check the car now because it’s back and I will take pictures to the engine if I didn’t find it or the photo is not 100% matching my engine

Comment: I have deleted this picture because mine doesn’t have this pipe

Comment: still should be in the same location. this pipe in the front is just the oily back flow. If you order the new part, I´m sure you´ll recognize the form.
https://justgermanparts.co.uk/a3-golf-bora-leon-ibiza-16-petrol-pressure-relief-breather-pcv-valve-06a103467e-6088-p.asp

Comment: Can you check the post picture because I kind lost how to install this valve if I order it and where it should go because there is no sign of place for it. Sorry to bother you but the mechanic guy did not help with that and he even mixed between the pcv and EGR valve

Comment: Changed the picture. Do you think it will do your car any good when you try to work on it, if you are so un-experienced? Don´t you have a friend or a self-help shop around where there is someone to give you a hand?

Comment: It’s not about that. In Finland we have car records and from this records they give you the part and with this it comes the problem that some car records have wrong technical record so for my car they have this problem. I have a decent experience in rebuilding engine strating from the camshafts down to crankshift but no experience in the other parts and that’s why there is no shame in asking people and the part you have shown I can find the location for it and instead of pretending that I know I asked you guys.